# Display image upload after page refresh

Tags: html, css, file, input, jscript

Hi i have a registration form with a avatar upload.

The form is working perfectly and i am happy with it, but i have 1 problem.

After i upload A avatar image and go onto the next page i can then go back to the registration page and the image remains in memory...

But i have no way of displaying it as i have no idea how to access the image as it is in memory somewhere.

But i can at this point complete my registration again without having to upload A image And the image is then displayed on the following page..

(the "required" is ignored in the form also as it has a file in memory)

Not sure if this explanation is doing me any favors but if any 1 can see from my code how i could again display the image if its in memory after a page refresh.

Thank you.

Simple Version.

"How Do I Access The Uploaded Image if Still in Memory And Display It Again On Page Refresh..."

```
    <form id='login-form' name='formsub' class='form' action='../imageupload/formfillsignup.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>


    <label id='usernamelabel'>UserName</label>   
    <input id='em1' type='name' name='username' placeholder='3-15 Characters ' pattern='^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\. ]{3,15}$'  autocomplete='new-password' required onChange='checkusername();' class='imp'/>


    <label id='emaillabel'>Email</label>     
    <input id='em2' type='email' autocomplete='new-email' placeholder='Standard Email Format Required' name='email' pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}'required onChange='alertemail();' class='imp' />


    <label id='passwordlabel'>PassWord</label>   <div class='reveal' id='revealPass' onclick='revealpasswords();' title='show/hide Passwords'></div>
    <input id='p1' type='password' autocomplete='new-password' placeholder='1 UpperCase + 1 Number' name='password' pattern='(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}'  required  onChange='alertpass();' class='imp' />


    <label id='confirmpasswordlabel'>Confirm PassWord</label> 
    <input id='p2' type='password' autocomplete='new-password' placeholder='1 UpperCase + 1 Number ' name='confirmpassword' pattern='(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}' required  onChange='checkPasswordMatch();' class='imp'/>




    <label class="custom-file-upload">
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="avatar" accept="image/*" required />

    <h7>Upload Avatar</h7>

    </label>


    <div class='image' id='imagediv'></div>

<button class='signupbutton' type='button' onclick='checkfile();'>Register</button>

</form>



<script>
            $(function () {

    $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase(),
            regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF|BMP)$");

        if (!(regex.test(val))) {
            $(this).val('');
           $("#signintext").text("JPG JPEG PNG BMP GIF ONLY"),  $("#signintext").css({"color":"#f40351"}), $( "#signintext" ).addClass( "errorglow" );
            $('#imagediv').css('background-image', 'url("../images/mainpage/uploadimage.jpg")');
            $('#imagediv').css('opacity','0.2');
        }else
            {
                        if (regex.test(val)) { 
                                    $("#signintext").text("Avatar Upload Completed"),  $("#signintext").css({"color":"#03f4bc"}) , $( "#signintext" ).removeClass( "errorglow" );
                                    var file = this.files[0];
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onloadend = function () {
                                       $('#imagediv').css('background-image', 'url("' + reader.result + '")');
                                        $('#imagediv').css('opacity','1');

                                    }
                                    if (file) {
                                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                    } else {
                                        var file1=document.getElementById('file1');
                                        file1.files.length == 0;
                                        $(file1).val('');
                                        return false;
                                    }



                        }

            }
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refreshed the DOM is completely rebuilt. To retain the image across refreshes use `localStorage`. When the image is uploaded for the first time you would save it locally. When the page loads you would check `localStorage` for the existence of an image; if the image is present then you would load it into your image frame.

You need to save the image in base64 encoding. To do this listen for the file upload change event, and then use `FileReader` to encode as a data URL.

```
document.getElementById("file1").addEventListener('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        localStorage.setItem("profileImageData", reader.result);
   };
} );
```

When the page is loaded you need to check `localStorage` and add the encoded image. Loading an encoded image as a CSS background in JavaScript doesn't work so you'll have to insert it as an image.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var profileImage = localStorage.getItem("profileImageData");
    if (profileImage !== null) {
        document.getElementyId("imagediv").innerHTML = "<img src='" + profileImage + "'>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. But the image is still in memory is what i am saying on page refresh or if i go back to the upload page. i wish to pull it from  memory and display again as it IS in memory, But where is it and how do i access it...Because i can submit my form without uploading any image and the last image is displayed